# Schedule Full Text Catalog Directly from Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, scheduling, full-text-catalog

I am migrating my Database to SQL Azure. Everything is working fine except scheduling Full-Text Catalog. I am somehow not able to schedule the Catalog.

I know we can use Scheduler but is there somehow anyway that I can directly schedule it directly through Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an option to do Scheduling directly in Azure SQL Database. However, as you seem to imply, there are ways to do this with Azure offerings- [see Elastic Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-jobs-overview), which is designed for scaling administrative tasks but also has a scheduling component.